# "help this community grow" ad link broken

Tags: support

The "Help this community grow" ad appears to be broken. Clicking it sends me to the 404 not found page on meta.gaming.

I clicked it from the home page to find this, but it is also broken on the [ad page](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/1892).

This is what the link ends up being in the browser bar:

> [meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/ads/ct/http%3a%2f%2ftwitter.com%2f%23!%2fstackgaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/ct/http://twitter.com/#!/stackgaming)

**Edit** 
This is broken on my iPad but not my desktop or laptop...so issue is something fringe-ish...

Comment: Been trying to repro this on my iPhone, but the darn ad won't appear. ):

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me in Chrome.  The link appears as

`.../ads/ct/1898?url=http%3a%2f%2ftwitter.com%2f%23!%2fstackgaming`

though, not

`.../ads/ct/http%3a%2f%2ftwitter.com%2f%23!%2fstackgaming`

Comment: thanks for reminding me about this question...I confirmed it was working for me (a few days ago)...but I know for sure that at some point, the URL posted above was what I was being sent to...however, I can't reproduce it anymore...

Comment: Edited post. Link broken on iPad...